# Flutter app throwing multiple errors when trying to run on Android device via USB debugging mode

Tags: flutter, debugging

I'm new to Flutter and trying to run a template app on my Android device via USB debugging mode. However, when I click "run", the console output log shows multiple errors.

**Output log**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth-3.4.0/lib/src/firebase_auth.dart:589:23: Error: The method 'signInWithAuthProvider' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseAuthPlatform'.
 - 'FirebaseAuthPlatform' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_firebase_auth.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.10.0/lib/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_firebase_auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'signInWithAuthProvider'.
      await _delegate.signInWithAuthProvider(provider),
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth-3.4.0/lib/src/recaptcha_verifier.dart:57:27: Error: Required named parameter 'auth' must be provided.
      _factory.delegateFor(
                          ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter_windows_3.7.8-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter_windows_3.7.8-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I'm not sure what these errors mean or how to fix them. Can someone please help me troubleshoot this issue and provide guidance on how to get my app running on my Android device?

**These are the versions I'm using:**

Flutter 3.7.8
• channel stable
• https://github.com/flutter/flutter.gitFramework
• revision 90c64ed42b (8 days ago)
• 2023-03-21 11:27:08 -0500Engine
• revision 9aa7816315Tools
• Dart 2.19.5
• DevTools 2.20.1

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps

```
   Delete your pubspec.lock
```

run following commands

```
   flutter channel stable
   flutter upgrade --force
   flutter pub cache repair
   flutter pub upgrade
   flutter clean
   flutter pub get
   flutter run --verbose
```

and then build the project again.

Comment: im getting a new error now i updated the out put log can you please see @Sagar Sable

Comment: updated answer added flutter pub upgrade to upgrade dependencies

Comment: Didn't work, it throws multiple errors as above

Comment: run flutter doctor -v and share  details